# What are these small pale spots on my pansy?

Tags: houseplants, leaves

[image]

Does anyone know what these spots are? They appear on the edge and bottom of the leaves. Only some of them get these spots. I'm not sure where they came from because I keep this pansy indoors.

Comment: Neem oil spray will counter most bugs non-toxically. And bugs do find their way indoors.